# SQL: Slow query Date with > operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, operator-keyword

I've used this query to find people with a birth date greater than "x":

```
SELECT ISNULL(matriculationNro, 0) 'matriculationNro'
FROM    matriculation m
INNER JOIN pupilFinance a ON a.pupilCode = m.pupilCode
INNER JOIN  OtherDB.dbo.pupil p ON RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',7) + p.pupilCode,7) END = m.pupilCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS   
WHERE   period = '2015-1'
AND     ISNULL(matriculationNro, 0) = 0
AND     ISNULL(a.anotherCode, '') <> 111
AND     ISNULL(a.anotherFlag, '') <> 'S'
AND     a.status = 'A'
AND     p.pupilBirth > (SELECT TOP 1 myBirthvariable FROM OtherDB.dbo.sysvariable)
```

The problem, it takes 6 seconds with the > or >= operator

[image]

I've tried with OUTER APPLY but the same, result:

```
SELECT ISNULL(matriculationNro, 0) 'matriculationNro'
FROM    matriculation m
INNER JOIN pupilFinance a ON a.pupilCode = m.pupilCode
INNER JOIN  OtherDB.dbo.pupil p ON RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',7) + p.pupilCode,7) END = m.pupilCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS   
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 myBirthvariable FROM OtherDB.dbo.sysvariable
) v
WHERE   period = '2015-1'
AND     ISNULL(matriculationNro, 0) = 0
AND     ISNULL(a.anotherCode, '') <> 111
AND     ISNULL(a.anotherFlag, '') <> 'S'
AND     a.status = 'A'
AND     p.pupilBirth > v.myBirthvariable
```

Is it possible to optimize it? I need a non-clustered index?

**Update**

Another way, but it takes 9 seconds!!

```
SELECT ISNULL(matriculationNro, 0) 'matriculationNro'
FROM    matriculation m
INNER JOIN pupilFinance a ON a.pupilCode = m.pupilCode
INNER JOIN (
    select  RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',7) + p.Pu_Compno,7) 'Code', pupilBirth
    from    OtherDB.dbo.pupil p
) x ON x.Code = m.pupilCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
WHERE   period = '2015-1'
AND     ISNULL(matriculationNro, 0) = 0
AND     ISNULL(a.anotherCode, '') <> 111
AND     ISNULL(a.anotherFlag, '') <> 'S'
AND     a.status = 'A'
AND     x.pupilBirth > v.myBirthvariable
```

Comment: Depending on how much data is being scanned, you could try using forceseek here:

INNER JOIN  OtherDB.dbo.pupil p with (forceseek) ON RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',7) + p.pupilCode,7) END = m.pupilCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: I believe your bottleneck is here `INNER JOIN  OtherDB.dbo.pupil p ON RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',7) + p.pupilCode,7)`

Comment: Is the query faster if you use a subquery rather than a subquery for the comparison?

Comment: Hi, i've tried with a inner join subquery, but it's slower.

Comment: Is the pupilBirth field indexed?

Answer (score -5):

Well depending on how often you will need the data you could always just create a view with the specified qualifications. Doing a `select * from` a vw that already contains the data you are looking for and only that data has always proven more efficient in my experience.